# Adding user input to a map and incrementing integer key by 1

Tags: java, string, dictionary, user-input

Fairly new to Java, and only just started doing maps, been trying for a few days with limited success to do the following, (comments in code) all suggestions welcome. Ideally, I would like to start from an unpopulated map and fill it purely with user input playerName and increment the integer value by one as each name is entered. Hope this follows all the guidelines!

```
/**
 * Constructor for objects of class player Creates player
 * objects and tests for unique player name
 */
public player() {
    Map<String, Integer> playerMap = new HashMap<>();
    System.out.println("Players in game: " + playerMap.isEmpty());
    playerMap.put("Fred", 1);
    playerMap.put("Bob", 2);
    playerMap.put("Alice", 3);
    playerMap.put("Charlotte", 4);
    playerMap.put("Catherine", 5);
    System.out.println("Players in game: " + playerMap.size());

    /**
     * user input via dialogue to get another playerName String
     * playerName set to Catherine for testing
     */
    String playerName = "Catherine";
    boolean existing = playerMap.containsValue(playerName);
    System.out.println(existing);
    if (existing = true) {
        int playerNumber = 5;
        /**
         * user input via dialogue to get another playerName I need
         * to set playerNumber = highest existing key in map then
         * increment by one then add values to map loop until all
         * players have been entered, I am considering while
         * (playerName != "last"); playerNumber set to 5 for
         * testing
         */
        playerNumber = playerNumber++;
        playerMap.put(playerName, playerNumber);
    }
}
```

Comment: `if (existing = true)` this is wrong. This is not how you compare a variable with a boolean value.

Comment: So what exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The method `containsValue` check if a value already exists in the map.

"Catherine" is not a value. It is a key.

Use `containsKey` instead.

Or probably you have inverted key and values. So create a `Map<Integer, String>` and put values on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can `iterate` instead of using `containsValue` , because containsValue internally traverse whole map.

```
private boolean exists(String playerName){
   boolean isExists=false;
   for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> playerEntry:playerMap.entry()){
     if(playerEntry.getValue().equals(playerName){
       isExists=true;
       break;
     }
   }
   return isExists;
 }
```

It is 50-50, in case the `map` does not contain the value it will traverse the whole map. If it contains the value it will break loop and returns `true`.

Then you can use below logic to `put` into `playerMap`

```
private void addToMap(String playerName){
 if(playerName!=null && exists(playerName)){
   playerMap.put(playerName, ++playerNumber);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement (existing = true) is wrong as a single "=" is assignment rather than comparison. If you want to compare two boolean values for equality use a double equals "==" to compare. In actual fact you don't even need to check if the "existing" variable is true as it is already a boolean, just surround the variable with an if statement and if it is true it will enter the if block otherwise it won't. Currently your code will always enter that if code block as you are assigning the "existing" variable to true.

Also as a previous poster has mentioned you are using names as keys not values so you should use the containsKey() method rather than the containsValue().

Below code should only enter the if block if your map contains the key "Catherine"

```
  String playerName = "Catherine";
  boolean existing = playerMap.containsKey(playerName);
  if (existing) {
    int playerNumber = 5;
    /**
     * user input via dialogue to get another playerName I need
     * to set playerNumber = highest existing key in map then
     * increment by one then add values to map loop until all
     * players have been entered, I am considering while
     * (playerName != "last"); playerNumber set to 5 for
     * testing
     */
    playerNumber = playerNumber++;
    playerMap.put(playerName, playerNumber);
}
```

Comment: Thank you all so much for help...working the past few days and will be able to get back into this tomorrow. Just processing all the new info! Yes, I do want the values to be the names and the keys to be the numbers. So the first field in map is the key and the second one the value? as in: Map<key, value> ? silly me.

Answer (score 0):

This code seems to have done the trick, and lists all the player names that have been entered as well, thanks for all the help, just wanted to post the final,  any other comments are welcome! Enjoying java very much....

```
 public player()
 {
  Map<Integer, String> playerMap = new HashMap<>();
  int playerNumber = 0;

 do
 {
  String playerName = 'user input request dialogue box' ("Please input a unique player name (5 Maximum): " + ((playerMap.size() - 10) * -1) + " Player slots left.");  
  boolean existing = playerMap.containsValue(playerName);                         
  System.out.println(existing);
  if (existing == false)
  {
    playerNumber = ++playerNumber;
    playerMap.put(playerNumber, playerName);
    System.out.println("Number of players in game: " + playerMap.size());

  }
} 
while (playerNumber < 5);


System.out.println("Players in game are:");
for (int a : playerMap.keySet())
{

  System.out.println("Player " + a + " is \"" + playerMap.get(a) + "\"" );



}

}
```